# Pivot table on two SQL table, one with 5m+ rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

Table cities has 2k rows

```
INT id
VARCHAR name
```

Table persons has 5M rows

```
VARCHAR person_id
INT city_id` (Foreign Key to table cities.id)
```

Note this is a one-to-many relationship.

I would like to get the following table:

```
VARCHAR city_name
INT count
```

in descending order by count

For example, if table city has 3 rows

```
id    city_name
1     San Francisco
2     Los Angeles
3     New York
```

and table persons has 3M rows that point to San Francisco, and 2M rows that point to Los Angeles, I would like the result to be:

```
city_name       count
San Francisco   3,000,000
Los Angeles     2,000,000
New York        0
```

Is this possible to do with just a SQL query when I have 5m rows?

Comment: What's your current SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this not do the trick?

```
SELECT 
    c.city_name, 
    COUNT(p.person_id) AS `count` 
FROM 
    cities c 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN persons p ON c.id = p.city_id 
GROUP BY 
    c.city_name
```

Comment: It will do providing there is and index on persons.city_id

Comment: It would still work without the index, just would be very slow.